# Разбиение предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Цитата (Пелам Вудхаус. Том 5. Дживс и Вустер):

> И однако, если бы я предложил твоей тетке рассказ о том, как девушка не может выйти замуж за любимого человека без согласия какого-то жалкого главы семейства, сама же твоя тетка меня бы и осмеяла.

Перед "если" стоит запятая, то есть получается, что "однако" относится к концу предложения ("и однако сама же твоя тётка...").

Вопрос: *будет ли вполне правильна фраза, если "однако" отнести к "если", то есть включить в придаточную часть **и убрать запятую**? И вообще, можно ли с уверенностью сказать, что в этом случае такое расчленение лучше (с запятой, чем без)?*

Прилагаю [ссылку](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/1004697/Vudhauz_Pelem_-_Tom_5._Dzhivs_i_Vuster.html) на 5-й том, чтобы можно было понять контекст.

Comment: Я не знаю,зачем Вы, Артём, издеваетесь над предложением, но по - хорошему Вам завидую: у Вас есть  время для чтения...

Comment: Издеваюсь? Хмм...)) А почему, кстати, Вы дефисы постоянно отделяете пробелами? Это ж не тире!

Comment: Честно говоря, я вообще не умею печатать: как бог на душу положит, так и пишу. Но спасибо Вам большое, что подсказали, теперь буду выделять правильно.

Comment: Да не за что.))

Answer (score 1):

Нормально читается с запятой перед "если", просто Вам не нравится сам стиль переводчика, соседство "и однако". "И" здесь, скорее всего, в роли усилительной частицы, а не союз. Уберите его, замените однако на "но", и всё встанет на свои места: "Но сама же твоя тетка меня бы и осмеяла". Так что всё нормально. Возможно и без запятой, но тогда будет мешать один из союзов, нужно будет убрать или И, или ОДНАКО. У автора акцент на противопоставленность - "и однако", это следует принять как его авторское право.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! *"Возможно и без запятой, но тогда будет мешать один из союзов, нужно будет убрать или И, или ОДНАКО".* Точно! Мне это и в голову не пришло! **Не могу понять только одного: почему Вы решили, что мне не нравится стиль переводчика и вообще этот его вариант!** *Наоборот, я понял, почему он так написал, **мне это не показалось странным или неудачным, но я просто захотел рассмотреть вариант без запятой и понять, хорош ли он тоже или нет.***

Comment: Я сужу по Вашей фразе "можно ли с уверенностью сказать, что в этом случае такое расчленение лучше (с запятой, чем без)?"

Comment: Ну да, я допустил, что оно может быть и хуже, но при этом не меньше допускал, что может быть не хуже или лучше. :) Просто хотелось рассмотреть такой теоретический вариант и сравнить их. ;)